Hilbert's theory of plane area (Foundations of Geometry)
I am studying Hilbert's Foundations of Geometry, and I do not understand the following claim about Pascal's Theorem and the theory of plane area, established just thanks to Pascal's Theorem itself: according to Hilbert, from the theorems on areas and equicomplementability, one can easily deduce Pascal's Theorem:

Theorem 48 claims that if two equicomplementable triangles have the same bases then they also have the same altitudes, while Theorem 46 claims the converse, i.e. that two triangles with equal basis and altitudes are equicomplementable.
What I do not understand in Hilbert's proof is the last argument: why Theorem 48 should imply necessarily that $BA'$ and $AB'$ are parallel? The triangles $OBB'$ and $OAA'$ have neither the same basis, nor the same altitudes, so why can we apply Theorem 48?
Thanks for any answer and help!

Triangles $OAA'$ and $OBB'$ have $OBA'$ in common. Subtracting that from both, we have that the remaining triangles $A'BA$ and $A'BB'$ must be equicomplementable. It follows that they have the same altitudes with respect to common base $A'B$, hence $AB'\parallel A'B$.
